how to make getSignaturebyAddress & getParsedTransactions on Solana ? More efficient and quick?
Currently, I am getting the signature from solana with an delay of 10/5 seconds to avoid 429 errors and then using those signatures to fetch the transactions using quicknode free tier and previously mainnet.
await delay(5000);
let transactionList = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(pubKey, options); 

const transactions = await connection.getParsedTransactions(Signatures,{ maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0 });

I was checking my transactions and logic based on dexscreener output, I realized it's atleast 30 seconds delayed and may sometimes skip transactions altogether.
How can I make the process of fetching signatures and transactions more efficient or quicker ? Would getting a paid rpc help with this, if yes I would like which would be the best to go for ?
Also, if their are any other alternatives which are more efficient. I would like some info as well.
Thank you!

Getting a paid RPC will definitely help, but I can't tell you exactly which one to get!
